# excel 2013 vba, how to use a loop to move data between workbooks based on unique identifier

Tags: vba, excel

I want to copy data from one workbook to another based on a shared unique identifier. I would like to loop through the cells in Column BP in Workbook 1, starting with Row 4, finding the matching cell value in Column BQ, starting with Row 6, of Workbook 2 and copying data associated that unique identifier from Workbook 2 to Workbook 1. My code is below, I'm getting a 'subscript out of range' error. I think it has to do with my DataCopy and DataPaste ranges, I want them to refer to the Row of the unique identifier in the for loop. I would appreciate any pointers that get me moving along. Thanks.

```
Sub cmdUpdate_Click()
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim Key1 As Range, Key2 As Range, DataCopy As Range, DataPaste As Range, Cell As Range, Cell2 As Range
Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet

Set wb1 = Workbooks("File Name")
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("File Path", ReadOnly:=True)
Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = wb2.Sheets("Sheet1")

LastRow = xlLastRow

Set Key1 = ws1.Range("BP6:BP" & LastRow)
Set Key2 = ws2.Range("BQ4:BQ" & LastRow)
Set DataCopy = ws2.Range("P:BK")
Set DataCopy = ws1.Range("P:BK")

For Each Cell In Key1
    Set Cell2 = Key2.Find(what:=Cell.Value, LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not Cell2 Is Nothing Then
        Rows.Range(DataCopy).Copy
        Rows.Range(DataPaste).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    End If
Next
End Sub

Function xlLastRow(Optional WorksheetName As String) As Long

 '    find the last populated row in a worksheet

If WorksheetName = vbNullString Then WorksheetName = ActiveSheet.Name
With Worksheets(WorksheetName)
    On Error Resume Next
    xlLastRow = .Cells.Find("*", .Cells(1), xlFormulas, _
    xlWhole, xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
    If Err <> 0 Then xlLastRow = 0
End With

End Function
```

Comment: On which line do you get the error?

Comment: You never set `DataPaste` but you set `DataCopy` twice in a row.

Comment: Thanks for catching that. Now I'm getting a Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error. The problem is

Comment: Sorry, problem is line; Rows.Range(DataCopy).Copy. It stops there and only selects the 'P' column, not 'P' through 'BK'. I'm not sure how to use a variable in that range to represent the row associated with the unique identifier.

Comment: DataCopy and DataPaste are already ranges so the proper method would be `DataPaste.Value = DataCopy.Value`

Comment: Using your suggestion, I now get an 'out of memory' error. I think I set the ranges for 'DataCopy' and 'DataPaste' incorrectly, I want them to refer to the matching unique identifiers row number. I'm just not sure how to go about doing that.

Comment: well you are pasting over 50 million cells.  You need to figure out how to set it to only the cells you want.